# How do I use the aws cli to set permissions on folder in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a one bucket called `world` and under that bucket there is one folder `world1`. I granted a list object access to everyone from `ACL` and also set a below bucket policy but still I am unable to access the stored object in `world1` folder. getting access denied error.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::world/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make the `world1` folder publicly accessible in the `world` bucket, use this **Bucket Policy**:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::world/world1/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

There is no need to change any ACLs.

This will grant permission to access/download/open any file in that directory. It will *not* grant permission to list the contents of the bucket.